# How to make HTML display a default string that is later replaced by a string taken from angular brackets?

Tags: javascript, html, object, ember.js, drop-down-menu

So at the moment in the handlebar file there is something like this:

```
<p>Colour Selected: {{selectedType.colour}}</p>
```

... where selectedType is an object from a .js file that looks something like:

```
selectedType: [{clothing: 'shirt', size: 'big', colour: 'blue'}, {clothing: 'socks', size: 'small', colour: 'red'}],
```

This is all part of an ember-power-select box that allows, for example, the website to immediately display *Colour Selected: blue* underneath when you select *shirt*.

This is all good but when nothing has been selected yet, the webpage only displays *Colour Selected:* without anything given. I want to change this so that by default *blue* will be shown until something has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, you can check if selectedType.colour is undefined or null. Assign default value to it If its  undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

You can write inline check like the below,

```
{{if selectedType.colour selectedType.colour selectedType.firstObject.colour}}
```